# How to set JTabbedPane Tab height width background foreground color (Both selected and Unselected Tab)

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

How to set the `JTabbedPane` Tab background and Foreground, Height and Width (Both selected and Unselected Tab)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set new values to the UIDefaults:

```
        UIDefaults def = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();
        def.put( "TabbedPane.foreground", Color.RED );
        def.put( "TabbedPane.textIconGap", new Integer(16) );
        def.put( "TabbedPane.background", Color.BLUE );
        def.put( "TabbedPane.tabInsets", new Insets(10,10,10,10) );
        def.put( "TabbedPane.selectedTabPadInsets", new Insets(10,20,10,20) );
```

here are a list of Keys

```
TabbedPane.textIconGap
TabbedPane.contentOpaque
TabbedPane.focus
TabbedPane.foreground
TabbedPane.tabRunOverlay
TabbedPane.shadow
TabbedPane.darkShadow
TabbedPane.background
TabbedPane.ancestorInputMap
TabbedPane.focusInputMap
TabbedPane.tabInsets
TabbedPane.light
TabbedPane.contentBorderInsets
TabbedPane.tabsOverlapBorder
TabbedPane.tabsOpaque
TabbedPane.tabAreaInsets
TabbedPane.highlight
TabbedPane.font
TabbedPane.selectedTabPadInsets
```

For Nimbus LookAndFeel there are some other [Nimbus Defaults](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html) like:

```
      TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTabArea.contentMargins
      TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTabArea[Enabled].backgroundPainter
      TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Selected].backgroundPainter
      TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTabArea[Enabled].backgroundPainter
      TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab.contentMargins
      TabbedPane.tabOverlap
```

Comment: and as I know by using Html for Disabled Tab(s) +1

Answer (score 2):

One way to change height and width of tabs is to use HTML and/or CSS in label of tab. You can use CSS padding attribute in HTML 'span' or 'p' element for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can control the height as follows:

```
JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
tabs.setUI(new BasicTabbedPaneUI() {
    @Override
    protected int calculateTabHeight(int tabPlacement, int tabIndex, int fontHeight) {
        return 45; // manipulate this number however you please.
    }
});
```

If each tab needs to be a different height, this answer might also be useful: [How to handle the height of the tab title in JTabbedPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054448/how-to-handle-the-height-of-the-tab-title-in-jtabbedpane)