# Nested tabs in Java

Tags: java, swing, layout, jtabbedpane

i'm trying to make nested tabs in java . It works but how can i resize my nested tabs ? ( addStudent, addTeacher ) because when it runs, they are very narrow. Thx for help

```
    JPanel students = new JPanel();
    JPanel teachers = new JPanel();
    JPanel lessons = new JPanel();
    JPanel courses = new JPanel();
    JPanel addPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel translations = new JPanel();
    JPanel addStudent = new JPanel();
    JPanel addTeacher = new JPanel();

    JButton bAddStudent = new JButton();
    //addStudent.setBounds(x, y, width, height);

    tp=new JTabbedPane();
    tp2 = new JTabbedPane();
    Container pane = this.getContentPane();
    pane.add(tp);
    tp.addTab("Uczniowie",students);
    tp.addTab("Nauczyciele",teachers);
    tp.addTab("Harmonogram zajec",lessons);
    tp.addTab("Kursy",courses);
    tp.addTab("Tlumaczenia", translations);
    tp.addTab("Panel administratora", addPanel);

    tp2.add("Nowy uczen",addStudent);
    tp2.add("Nowy nauczyciel",addTeacher);
    addPanel.add(tp2);
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994352/how-to-set-jtabbedpane-tab-height-width-background-foreground-color-both-select

Comment: I want to resize ONLY my nestet tabs , so i don't think i'm duplicating , sorry . Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

Change the layout manager of `addPanel` to a `BorderLayout`

This will allow `tp2` to occupy the entire available space provided by `addPanel` and `tp`

I'd also be careful with nested tabs, it becomes very messy and confusing to user very quickly